# Display multiple images in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, imshow

How do I use the matlib function plt.imshow(image) to display multiple images?

For example my code is as follows:

```
for file in images:
    process(file)

def process(filename):
    image = mpimg.imread(filename)
    <something gets done here>
    plt.imshow(image)
```

My results show that only the last processed image is shown effectively overwriting the other images

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46616645/7887458 would work if you make ncols = 1.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can set up a framework to show multiple images using the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

def process(filename: str=None) -> None:
    """
    View multiple images stored in files, stacking vertically

    Arguments:
        filename: str - path to filename containing image
    """
    image = mpimg.imread(filename)
    # <something gets done here>
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image)

for file in images:
    process(file)
```

This will stack the images vertically

Comment: how to stack horizontally?

Answer (score 60):

To display the multiple images use subplot()

```
plt.figure()

#subplot(r,c) provide the no. of rows and columns
f, axarr = plt.subplots(4,1) 

# use the created array to output your multiple images. In this case I have stacked 4 images vertically
axarr[0].imshow(v_slice[0])
axarr[1].imshow(v_slice[1])
axarr[2].imshow(v_slice[2])
axarr[3].imshow(v_slice[3])
```

Comment: What is `v_slice` here? @AadharBhatt

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory It stands for vertical slice, as we are using 4 images which are sacked vertically.

Answer (score 12):

In first instance, load the image from file into a numpy matrix

```py
from typing import Union,List
import numpy
import cv2
import os
def load_image(image: Union[str, numpy.ndarray]) -> numpy.ndarray:
    # Image provided ad string, loading from file ..
    if isinstance(image, str):
        # Checking if the file exist
        if not os.path.isfile(image):
            print("File {} does not exist!".format(imageA))
            return None
        # Reading image as numpy matrix in gray scale (image, color_param)
        return cv2.imread(image, 0)

    # Image alredy loaded
    elif isinstance(image, numpy.ndarray):
        return image

    # Format not recognized
    else:
        print("Unrecognized format: {}".format(type(image)))
        print("Unrecognized format: {}".format(image))
    return None
```

Then you can plot multiple image using the following method:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def show_images(images: List[numpy.ndarray]) -> None:
    n: int = len(images)
    f = plt.figure()
    for i in range(n):
        # Debug, plot figure
        f.add_subplot(1, n, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i])

    plt.show(block=True)
```

The `show_images` method take in input a list of images that you can read iteratively using the `load_image` method.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `plt.show()` after `plt.imshow(image)` while in the for loop worked for me.

```py
for file in images:
    process(file)
    
def process(filename):
    image = mpimg.imread(filename)
    # <something gets done here>
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: this is a short n sweet approach

Answer (score 0):

Building on Aadhar Bhatt's answer:

```
from matplotlib.image import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v_slice = [] #create an empty list called v_slice
for i in range(0,4):
    image = imread("test.png") #Here I load the same image 4 times-replace this  with code that generates images
    v_slice.append(image)


#Aadhar Bhatt's answer
plt.figure()
#subplot(r,c) provide the no. of rows and columns
f, axarr = plt.subplots(4,1) 
# use the created array to output your multiple images. In this case I have stacked 4 images vertically
axarr[0].imshow(v_slice[0])
axarr[1].imshow(v_slice[1])
axarr[2].imshow(v_slice[2])
axarr[3].imshow(v_slice[3])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How do you view the output?

Comment: So, I just ran the code above in a jupyter notebook cell. You can literally just copy/paste my code into jupyter notebook. Make sure that you have a file called test.png that is in the same directory as your project. (The default directory is C:/Users/yourusername if you're not sure where your project is). Then the output (picture) will appear below the cell.

I installed Anaconda Navigator and then Jupyter notebook, instructions here: https://sparkbyexamples.com/python/install-anaconda-jupyter-notebook/