# How to seperate the drawn figures by matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've written a code and it gives me 3 graphs(i use matplotlib) but all of them are in 1 figure like the picture:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = []
y = []
TaList = []
TbList = []
for i in range(0, 21):
if i != 0 :
    a = (i/2)
    x.append(a)
    b = (math.sqrt(((4.01+40*(a))/40.2)**2 - (a**2)))
    y.append(b)
    alpha = math.atan(b/a)
    beta = math.atan(b/(20-a))
    Ta = (800/((math.tan(beta)*(math.cos(alpha)) + math.sin(alpha))))
    TaList.append(Ta)
    Tb = (800/((math.tan(alpha)*(math.cos(beta)) + math.sin(beta))))
    TbList.append(Tb)



plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, TaList)
plt.plot(x, TbList)

plt.show()
```

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttC1Z.png)

so my question is how can i seperate these 3 graphs into 3 different figures? i mean i don't want them to be together in 1 picture! i want them in 3 different pictures  and each alone !

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615554/how-to-display-multiple-images-in-one-figure-correctly/46616645)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to take the

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, TaList)
plt.plot(x, TbList)
plt.show()
```

out of your loop. Then, after the loop, plot each one separately like

```
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

plt.plot(x, TaList)
plt.show()

plt.plot(x, TbList)
plt.show()
```