# How can I plot 10 fits files in python with imshow and color bar?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, fits

This is my code and it only opens one fits image, I don't know why if I'm reading all the images inside my folder (there are 10). Does anyone know how to solve it? Thank you.

```
 f_name = sorted(glob.glob('/home/citlali/img_servicio/*.fits'))


for location in f_name:
    with fits.open(location) as image:
        DATOS = image["FLUX_ELINES"].data

        img = DATOS[45, :, :]
        plt.imshow(img)
        image.close()
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Like some sample data and specify from which library are you importing the `fits` function.

Comment: What does `print(f_name)` return? Are you sure you're looping over all the files ?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210823/using-plt-imshow-to-display-multiple-images ?